# Avoid empty rows in SQL where case when and group by is in use

Tags: sql, db2

The following SQL delivers the right result which i want, but the data output contains empty rows too, which I dont want.

```
Select
v.ID
,max(case when v.param = 'param_1' then v.pValue end) as param1
,max(case when v.param = 'param_2' then v.pValue end) as param2
,max(case when v.param = 'param_3' then v.pValue end) as param3
from
datasource v
Group by v.ID
```

For example to solve this Problem, one could serround the SQL above with a second one and set a filter like "where parama1 is not null". But I would like to do it in the same Statement, avoiding (do not inclued) all rows in which all tree param columns are null or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `WHERE` clause to only include rows that have at least on of the param values:

```
Select
    v.ID
    ,max(case when v.param = 'param_1' then v.pValue end) as param1
    ,max(case when v.param = 'param_2' then v.pValue end) as param2
    ,max(case when v.param = 'param_3' then v.pValue end) as param3
from
    datasource v
where v.param in ('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3')
Group by v.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` statement:

```
select v.ID
       max(case when v.param = 'param_1' then v.pValue end) as param1,
       max(case when v.param = 'param_2' then v.pValue end) as param2,
       max(case when v.param = 'param_3' then v.pValue end) as param3
from datasource v
group by v.ID
having  max(case when v.param = 'param_1' then v.pValue end) is not null;
```